# Convolution Case

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

The * denotes convolution and u[n] as the heaviside function.

$x[n]= u[n]α^n$

Determine a sequence $h[n]$ such that-:

$x[n]∗h[n]=α^n(u[n+2]−u[n−2])$

I am trying this problem for quite awhile now. Can someone shed some light as to which is the proper path to take. Im thinking of taking the fourier transform of the L.H.S and then solve it algebrically followed by an inverse fourier transform but I get lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $x[n] = \alpha^n$ for $n \geq 0$ and

$x[n]*h[n] = \alpha^n-1$ for $n \geq 2$

$x[n]*h[n] = -1$ for $ -2 \leq n \leq 1$

$x[n]*h[n] = 0$ else

You just have to pick clever values of $h[n]$ such as $h[n] = (1-\frac{1}{\alpha^n})$ and multiply by various variants of step functions to match the above requirements.

Comment: math exchange didnt include the curly brackets. I have revised it but I get your idea. However, considering the previous version, if we use n=1, how can x[n]∗h[n]=−1. Shouldnt it be equal to α.

Comment: Yes it should, maybe I misread your original post (or did you edit?). I thought the second step was outside of the parenthesis.

Comment: It should be but somehow the curly bracket is not read so I revised it and added the simple bracket. However I built upon your idea and solved it finally. Thanks